# Call to undefined function json_encode - Drupal site setup on Ubuntu 14.04 and phpbrew

Tags: php, json, ubuntu

I am a newbie to PHP/Apache world. Installed `phpbrew` by following the instructions of https://askubuntu.com/questions/550191/install-php-5-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-without-compiling on Ubuntu 14.04 and switched to PHP version 5.3.29 because the application I have to work on is developed in this version. I configured `Apache Virtual Host` and modified `hosts` file to load my application as `local.myapp.com`. When I am running the application I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /var/www/myapp/myapp.main.drupal/includes/common.inc on line 2563

I looked into https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew#variants which says I can install variants. Setting up Ubuntu, phpbrew and finally the application took a long time (sorry I have stepped into PHP world recently).

I am worried if I install just the JSON variant using `phpbrew install 5.3.29 +json` will it be a completely new install and all my settings will get wiped out?

Please suggest me if there is a way which I should follow to install JSON (if I am really missing it) without affecting existing settings!

Thank you.

**EDIT**

If I have understood right, when I installed PHP using `phpbrew` for some reason it compiled without JSON altough I used `phpbrew install +default`?

**EDIT #2**
I checked phpbrew.variants file. It shows that JSON is enabled.

> /home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29/phpbrew.variants
>   a:3:{s:16:"enabled_variants";a:27:{s:4:"intl";b:1;s:3:"xml";b:1;s:6:"bcmath";b:1;s:3:"bz2";b:1;s:8:"calendar";b:1;s:3:"cli";b:1;s:5:"ctype";b:1;s:3:"dom";b:1;s:8:"fileinfo";b:1;s:6:"filter";b:1;s:3:"ipc";b:1;s:4:"json";b:1;s:7:"mbregex";b:1;s:8:"mbstring";b:1;s:5:"mhash";b:1;s:6:"mcrypt";b:1;s:5:"pcntl";b:1;s:4:"pcre";b:1;s:3:"pdo";b:1;s:4:"phar";b:1;s:5:"posix";b:1;s:8:"readline";b:1;s:7:"sockets";b:1;s:9:"tokenizer";b:1;s:4:"curl";b:1;s:7:"openssl";b:1;s:3:"zip";b:1;}s:17:"disabled_variants";a:0:{}s:13:"extra_options";a:0:{}}

However, I went ahead again to install the extension after giving write permission to the folder and then I got this (sorry, its long :( ):

> subrara@subrara-desktop:~$ phpbrew ext install json stable
>
> ===> Installing json extension...
>
> Log stored at: /home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json/build.log
>   Changing directory to /home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json
>
> ===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json' --quiet 'clean'
>
> ===> Phpize...
>
> ===> Configuring...
>
> ===> Building...
>
> ===> Running make all: /usr/bin/make -C '/home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json' 'all'  >> '/home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json/build.log' 2>&1
>
> ===> Installing...
>
> ===> Running make install: /usr/bin/make -C '/home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json' 'install'  >> '/home/subrara/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.29/ext/json/build.log' 2>&1
>
> ===> Extension is installed.
>
> ===> Creating config file /home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29/var/db/json.ini.disabled
>   PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 95
>
> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 95
>   PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29/var/db/json.ini.disabled): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 109
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29/var/db/json.ini.disabled): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/src/PhpBrew/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 109
>
> ===> Enabling extension json
>   json extension is not installed. Suggestions:
>       $ phpbrew ext install json

Answer (score 3):

Debian has removed the previous JSON extension as of PHP 5.5rc2 due to a license conflict.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Don't forget to restart your http server.

---

For `phpbrew` you should reassemble the build with `+json`.

Simple way:
  Just backup your php configurations to protect them from being rewritten.

Other:
  Try to use `phpbrew ext install json` [Wiki](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Extension-Installer)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Question is because I installed PHP using `phpbrew` will `apt-get` installation add the package to my current PHP version and compile? And will this keep all settings made with `phpbrew` intact? Sorry again. I am probably asking a lot of childish questions. Please consider my newbie status!

Comment: I switched to 5.3.29 (`sudo phpbrew switch php-5.3.29`) and tried `phpbrew ext install json stable` but ended up with   **# WARNING: curl extension might be required for fetching data.
Error: PHPBREW_PHP environment variable is not defined.
  This extension command requires you specify a PHP version from your build list.
  And it looks like you haven't switched to a version from the builds that were built with PHPBrew.
Suggestion: Please install at least one PHP with your prefered version and switch to it.**

Answer (score 1):

Finally JSON extension is installed with `phpbrew ext install json` command. Thanks to vp_arth for letting me know about this option!

Step 1: Ran `sudo chmod 777 /home/subrata/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29` to give **php-5.3.29** folder full permission so that the installer can create php-5.3.29/var/db/json.ini.disabled. Initially it was a permission issue and these folders and the file could not be written inside php-5.3.29 folder.

Step 2: Ran `sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/subrata/.phpbrew/php/php-5.3.29` to change user and group to current user.

Step 3: Ran `phpbrew ext install json` again and extension got installed.

May be there is another way to do this but the above worked for me.